# Creating a compendium of fitness and nutrition apps?

Tags: discussion

There have been a few question regarding website for [tracking fitness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1142/any-social-website-for-sharing-and-tracking-fitness-workouts) and [monitoring running workouts](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/13/what-can-i-use-to-monitor-my-running-workout).

Numerous websites have been mentioned in a bunch of answers. What do people think blogging about common sites people use?

Some of the web/mobile/desktop apps mentioned include:

- [SportTracks](http://www.zonefivesoftware.com/SportTracks/)
- [dailymile](http://www.dailymile.com/)
- [PaceMaker](http://pacemakerapp.com/)
- [Endomondo](http://www.endomondo.com/)
- [MyFitnessPal](http://www.myfitnesspal.com/)
- [JEFIT](http://www.jefit.com/)
- [Fitocracy](http://www.fitocracy.com/)
- [Fatbet](http://fatbet.net/)
- [RunKeeper](http://www.runkeeper.com/)
- [DailyBurn](http://tracker.dailyburn.com)

Comment: My question was rather specifically aimed at running, while most seem to offer more features. Perhaps it would be better if we did it as a blog post instead?

Comment: I'm reversing my stance on the community wiki idea. I dug through some historical stuff, and realized that this would be a bad idea for the site. Doing it as blog posts would be a better outlet as you mentioned.

Comment: Agree that a blog is probably a better idea. I tried to do something similar as a community wiki with diet plans & commercial supplements early on, and it was not well-received (by users or SE management).

Comment: I made Evertrainer.com as a lightweight program builder/tracker. Might be worth adding it to the list ;)

Answer (score 4):

I suggest we make a blog post about this, I think the apps you listed already enumerate the most popular ones, though we might have to look at some platform specific ones (like Nike+)

We should start with listing all the features we want to compare:

- Price
- Mobile and/or Web App available
- Major features

  - Training programs
  - GPS tracking
  - Diet/calorie counter
  - Social sharing
- Accessories (required or optional)

  - Heart rate monitor
  - Accelerometer
  - GPS-receiver

Given that not everybody can try out every app, we should get several users to pitch in to help review their favorite app. I guess its better to focus on quality than quantity, besides we can always post an updated version (like on a monthly or quarterly basis) that incorporates new apps.

Here's a list of apps and the users that want to review them:

- [DailyBurn](https://tracker.dailyburn.com/v)
- [dailymile](http://www.dailymile.com/)
- [Endomondo](http://www.endomondo.com/)
- [Fatbet](http://fatbet.net/)
- [Funbeat](http://www.funbeat.se)
- [Fitocracy](http://www.fitocracy.com/)
- [Jawbone UP](http://jawbone.com/up)
- [JEFIT](http://www.jefit.com/)
- [Health Month](http://healthmonth.com/)
- [Suunto Movescount](http://www.movescount.com/)
- [Micoach](http://www.micoach.com) - Ivo
- [MyFitnessPal](http://www.myfitnesspal.com/)
- [Nike+](http://www.apple.com/ipod/nike/)
- [PaceMaker](http://pacemakerapp.com/)
- [RunKeeper](http://www.runkeeper.com/)
- [Runtastic](http://www.runtastic.com/)
- [SportsCam](http://www.ubersense.com/extremecam)
- [SportTracks](http://www.zonefivesoftware.com/SportTracks/)
- [Sports Tracker](http://www.sports-tracker.com/) - Ivo
- [SwingReader](http://www.swingreader.com/)
- [WorkSmart Labs, Inc. Products](http://www.worksmartlabs.com/products/)

  - [Calorific](http://www.worksmartlabs.com/calorific/)
  - [CardioTrainer](http://www.worksmartlabs.com/cardiotrainer/about.php)
  - [Noom Weight Loss](http://www.worksmartlabs.com/noom/)
- [TheSquatRack.com](http://thesquatrack.com/)
- [strengthcalc.com](https://strengthcalc.com/)

Accessories:

- Heart Rate Monitor - Ivo
- <s>[SportGrips SideWinder](http://www.sportgrips.com/) - Matt Chan</s> **COMPLETE**

We also have a budget to sponsor apps or products that cost some money, like Runkeeper Pro or using an app with a HR monitor or FitBit. I'd suggest we couple those with a general review we can post on the blog as well.

This might take us a few weeks to compile, but I'm sure we can get cracking at it. I made this post CW so anyone who wants to add features or want to review an app, feel free to edit it.

Comment: The apps would fit nicely under one blog category. Instead of doing straight reviews though, I think doing a post that's more introductory and explaining what the app is and its features would be a better avenue for people to decide whether an app is for them or not.

Comment: AFAIK Jawbone UP is not sold anymore due to a failure in circuit design (a capacitor, I think it was). I think this is a fantastic idea and I will be looking forward to the blog entries!

Comment: The UP will soon be on the market again according to Jawbone

Answer (score 1):

Being a longtime user and a big fan of this app I would suggest Gymprovise also as a Gym/Bodybuilding app to add to the list (which does routine creation, workout tracking, progress monitoring etc). Though it seems to be only available for Android AFAIK. Link [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gymProvise.ui)

(Wanted to add this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation)

Answer (score 0):

There are tables of the Fitness and Nutrition apps that sync with [Google Fit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Fit) and [Apple Health](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_(application)) on Wikipedia.

I also started to compile a matrix of features supported by the different Tracker app's a while ago, this incomplete table can be found in [Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/a/arcalot.net/spreadsheets/d/1SYNqKopu_3bzwZ_O8jGKafwwd7_bcCEgxs4DyFrA3vg/edit?usp=sharing) (wish Google would add proper support for rotated text)

[image]